# MVC 4 Clientside Validation not firing

Tags: jquery, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a view that contains a RenderPartial tag. within the partial view I have a form but clientside form validation isn't firing prior to server request. The serverside validation is working fine. it's odd since I have other views but without RenderPartials which work perfectly. it seems when I include a RenderParial it seems cause the validation to stop working.

BTW - I have set both webconfig settings to true:

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

also, the model has been updated to include [Required] attributes. here is a snapshot:

```
[Required]
[CreditCard]
public string CardNumber { get; set; }

[Required]
[Display(Name = "Name on card")]
public string CardHolder { get; set; }

[Required]
public string Address { get; set; }
```

Here is the parent snippet:

```
@if (ViewBag.tabvalue.Equals("billing"))
{
<div>
    <p>
        @{Html.RenderPartial("_BillingInfo");}
    </p>
</div>
}
```

Here is the child partial view (i removed some of the fields to lessen the amount of copy):

```
@model MVC4.Models.ClientCreditCard

@using (Html.BeginForm("CreditCard", "Client", FormMethod.Post, new { }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <fieldset style="color:white">
        <legend></legend>
        <div style="color:white;clear:left">@Html.ValidationSummary(true)</div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CardNumber)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CardNumber)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CardNumber)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CardHolder)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CardHolder)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CardHolder)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

Thanks for you help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you didn't include JQuery validation files in the view.
So, your client side validation didn't work. You need to write the following code in your view.

```
@section scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Client validation should be working fine if:

1. `jquery.validate.js` , `validate.unobtrusive.js` included
2. `ClientValidationEnabled`, `UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled` set to
   true
3. The form should loaded before `document.ready` triggered

`RenderPartial` will not causing problem if your form loaded the normal way. I mean do you load the form using ajax (your form loaded after `document.ready` triggered)? if yes then you should manually parse the form by adding:

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse('<your_form_selector>');
```

NOTE:
a form that parsed correctly by jquery validator will having `novalidate="novalidate"` attribute. check your form if it is having one to start trouble shooting.